# Check if value exists in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to MySQl and I'm trying to check if an inputed email matches with any from my table. If it matches, I need to put the email and the other columns of the same row in another table.

What I get now is a blank row added to table2.

```
<?php
include "config.php";

$email = $_POST['email'];

$match = mysqli_query("SELECT email FROM table1 WHERE email = $email"); 

if($conn->query($match)){
    //here i have to find the name, school, and grad_year that matches
    // with the email from table 1 which is in the same row. I tried a couple of 
    //things but it didn't work. So i don't know what to put in there.

    $insert = "INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(name,'$email',school,grad year )";

    $conn->query($insert);
}
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use either `num_rows()` or `COUNT()`. Plus this will give you problems `grad year`. Matter 'o fact, 75% of this line `(name,'$email',school,grad year )` will give you problems.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're exactly asking.  Why not pull all the information from table1 (assuming it's all there) .  if the response is null no insert

Comment: Actually, I can't see how this code would possibly even work. `WHERE email = $email` is another code fail.

Comment: why would the where clause fail?

Comment: @DCR Try it out for yourself. I guarantee it will fail. Unless email is an integer (which I highly doubt); fail. Not to mention the rest of OP's code. Breaking a few of SQL's rules ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't *ever* use the mysql* functions. They are deprecated and insecure. Use mysqli* or PDO instead. See below for *sample* code (I have NOT run it and there may be errors - the idea is to get you on the right road...)

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$email = $_POST['email'];

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE email=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    # NOTE: You may prefer $stmt->get_results() and $result->fetch_assoc()
    # to this $stmt->bind_result() and $stmt->fetch().
    $stmt->bind_result($name, $junk, $school, $grad_year);

    /* fetch value */
    if ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt2->bind_param("ssss", $name, $email, $school, $grad_year);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $stmt2->close();
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Or, if you don't care to know details along the way, this is a lot faster and simpler:

```
// yada,yada - get a conx
$email = $_POST['email'];

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE email=?")) {
    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* the total number of affected rows can be determined by using the mysqli_stmt_affected_rows() function */
}
```

(SOURCE: Example copied from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php and modified)

Comment: Great answer. Now, what about the OP's code as to why it's failing in the first place? *Ah,* that is the "question". But this `INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE email=?` was that in the manual? I doubt it. That will fail.

Comment: Too many difficulties with the original code to try to address each one. Easier to start from scratch (especially since OP was using deprecated mysql* functions and no prepared statements).  And, no, the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` wasn't in the manual page I referred to - after you asked I googled and found reference here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Comment: I for one, don't know what the OP's db schema is and contains too many errors in their code to be absolutely sure. Let's see what they have to say. It could very well be what they're looking for. However, I myself like to explain to an OP, why their present code is failing. Unquoted values and spaces, etc.